# Displaying image in UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uibutton

To preface this question, I am extremely new to Objective-C and Xcode. I have only been learning for a week or so now but I have been stuck on this problem for a few days. I am trying to display an image in a UIButton. I have 3 to choose from, blue.png, purple.png and orange.png. No matter what I do or what image I tell Xcode to use, it will only display the blue image. I have deleted the image from the project entirely. I have "reset content and settings" in the iOS simulator. What exactly is going on here?

the.h code

```
IBOutlet UIButton *h1;
```

the.m code

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"purple.png"];
[h1 setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:h1];
```

No matter which image I specify within the quotes, it always uses blue.png, even when the image no longer exists in the project. Thanks for the help everybody!

Comment: Are you able to get your images to display elsewhere? Have you made sure your image isn't nil?

Comment: I know the image is working because I am displaying a background image also. And if I change the code to have the image display on another button, then that button will just display the blue image. I will use a switch and a random to have the buttons display each image randomly and they all just turn out blue. I am also using the orange.png to color an ImageView and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have set `blue.png` as the background image in the storyboard or xib file. Write NSLog(@"%@",buttonImage) to make sure that the image is not nil. Make sure that you are entering the correct name and extension `purple.png`

And also, use

```
[h1 setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

instead of `setImage`

Comment: I will give this a try and report back.

Comment: That worked to get the images to update and display correctly! Can someone explain why xcode was using an image that did not exist as the default? I also had to attempt to change the image of the button before the default would display. I really do want to understand xcode better, it is very different from the other IDE's I have used. Thanks again, yall help me out so much every time I need it. You rock!

Answer (score 1):

I think first of all you should know the difference button.image and button.backgroundImage.

> Using the Image (currentImage) field, you can specify an image to
>   appear within the content of your button. If the button has a title,
>   this image appears to the left of it, and centered otherwise.
>
> The Background (currentBackgroundImage) field allows you to specify an
>   image to appear behind button content and fill the entire frame of the
>   button.

So you can use setImage or setBackgroundImage as what you want.

Comment: Good piece of info I will use. Thanks!